# how to add these settings to my php.ini in docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using docker-compose, and I want to add this setting to my php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

but I'm confused I have 2 php.ini, please see the screenshot

how can I persist my additional setting to the php.ini?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `docker cp <php_container_name>:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development .` to copy the ini file from the container to host. Change the settings as you like then mount the edited file into the container. In the compose file add this to your `php` service:

```yaml
  volumes:
    - /home/user/my-edited-php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

It should appear in the directory inside the container as `php.ini`.

Comment: is this will persist ?, if I will down the container and up again does it still there ?

Comment: Yes, this will link the file on your host to the container. So it will be there as long as it stays on host. You can get further by building an image with it (for that you need a Dockerfile) but I recommend to delayt hat to when you are ready to deploy the container.

Comment: Personally I dont find that this works for me; any changes to the local php.ini are not reflected even after a `docker compose up -d --build` -- I can tell from a `phpinfo()`